# Relation between the size of TensorFlow's checkpoint file and number of parameters

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to know the relation between the size of TensorFlow's checkpoint file and the number of parameters of a model.

I have a model with `1.8` million parameters, which should require about `7` MB of memory (given that `(4 * 1.8 * 10^6) / 1024^2`). However, the saved checkpoint is apparently larger

```
model-5000.data-00000-of-00001   15MB
model-5000.index  15K
```

In Caffe, the fraction of 4 seems always right with `caffemodel`.

Comment: It would be nice to have a very simple reproducible piece of code that we could execute and observe the "unexplained" results.

Comment: @nbro is 7 MB expected? or as Burton2000 explained, further process needs to be down for final model

Answer (score 1):

Did you use an optimizer with momentum? That will double the number of saved parameters (each parameter will have a corresponding momentum parameter). If you used Adam, the number of saved parameters will actually be tripled, because of the squared-gradient estimators. Other optimizers will vary in different ways.

You can [manually inspect the checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#manually_inspecting_checkpoints) to see what variables are being stored.

Answer (score -1):

I would say the checkpoint file is not 100% comparable to a .caffemodel file. It will contain many more things in it besides the model params, e.g. loading data nodes, weight initializers, saver nodes etc. Also params will be saved as trainable variables which takes up more space I would think.

To get something comparable to caffe's .caffemodel you need to convert your variables to constants (called freezing the graph) and then save graph as a binary proto file (.pb). Doing this will remove all unncessary nodes in the graph.

To conert to .pb you cna do soething like the following:

```
 output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess,                       # The session is used to retrieve the weights
        sess.graph_def,             # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
        output_node_names           # The output node name
    ) 

    # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
    with open('mode.pb', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```